# Where would you begin analysing this?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, anova, linear

I would really appreciate your help. Despite enjoying stats, this issue has been very much bugging me and I can't get my head around it. Everytime I make a breakthrough I end up back at square one.

I have an analysis to complete. I'm looking at whether attractiveness ratings (7 point Likert scale) differ on the basis of waist-to-hip ratio (WHR) and BMI. I also measured participants sociosexual orientation (SIO).

Both WHR (0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0) and BMI (Emaciated, Under, Normal, Over, Obese) are categorical and SIO is continuous (0-100).

I guess what I'm interested in is whether WHR and BMI influence attractiveness ratings, which is a simple within-subject ANOVA (attractrating ~ WHR*BMI, data). But then when adding in the SIO scores it becomes confusing. I'm looking at whether a person's SIO influences their attractiveness ratings. Do they prefer lower BMI/WHR? I assume this serves as a moderator term? So it would make sense to then model this as an ANCOVA and include an interaction between WHR/SIO and BMI/SIO. But, then I have read that using an ANCOVA with within-subject predictors presents issues - and that SIO would need to be mean centered, which may reduce it's interpretability.

Any help would be appreciated as this is stressing me.

Answer (score 1):

From the description, it seems that you have repeated measures within participants, and presumably within whatever it is that the participants are rating. So a model with random intercepts for these would make sense.

If you are going to interact `SIO` with `WHR*BMI` then indeed it will make sense to centre it, since the other estimates will be conditional on `SIO` being 0 - so if you mean-centre it, then it will be conditional on it being at it's mean. On the other hand, if it makes sense to have an `SIO` score of 0, then there is no need to centre it. The same is also true of `WHR` and `BMI` - when these are included in an interaction then it will make sense to centre these too - otherwie the other estimates will be conditional on `WHR = 0` and `BMI = 0`